# MaterialUI MenuItem props name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm doing a map on an array to display my list of items, therefore I'd like to pass another property except the value, but I found no way to do it.

```
<Select
   style={{width:'100%'}}
   value={props.summary.products.find(product=>x.id === product.id )?.description}
   variant="outlined"
   onChange={event=>{x.id !== undefined && handleDescriptionChange(event,x.id)}}
 >
  {x.id !== undefined && ProductLists[value[x.id]]?.map((product)=>{
    return <MenuItem key={product?.description} value={product?.description}>{product?.description}</MenuItem>
  })}
 </Select>
```

this is my handling function and i need to have another key state either in event.target.name or any other way :

```
  const handleDescriptionChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<{value:unknown,name?:string}>,id:number) => {
    const selected = event.target.value as string
    props.handleProductDescriptionChange(selected,id)}
```

I have another key in product which is STATE and I need to use that value in my handler function.
Is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: Did I understand correctly, you want to pass another property to `<MenuItem/>`, except `key` and `value`?

Comment: Yes basically I have a key in my object that I need to use and I need a find a way to get it in my handler function